# how do you link your park with Facebook

Tags: dragonvale, facebook

Please can someone help me? My device is going to be reset completely, and I don't know how to link my park with my Facebook account so i don't lose my progress. Please help!

I have tried doing what the Dragonvale FAQ says to do but there is no "log in with
Facebook icon in the corner of the settings screen" so I have got genuinely no clue 
about what to do.   Is my Dragonvale bound to my Kindle Fire or something?